# JNA Callback function with void * argument

Tags: java, c++, jna

What is the correct way to map a callback function that has void* as an argument?

I am working with native library (.dll) using JNA.
Library defines the following callback function:

`typedef void (__stdcall *NotifyFunc)(int code, void *value);`.

Here is how it is mapped in java:

```
public static NatLib.NotifyFunc notifyFunction = new MyNotifyFuncImpl();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    NatLib.INSTANCE.SetCallbackFunc(notifyFunction);
}

public interface NatLib extends Library {

    NatLib INSTANCE = Native.load("Nat.dll", NatLib.class);

    //...

    void SetCallbackFunc(NotifyFunc func);

    interface NotifyFunc extends Callback {
        void MyNotifyFunc(int code, Pointer value);
    }
}

public static class MyNotifyFuncImpl implements NatLib.NotifyFunc {

    @Override
    public void MyNotifyFunc(int code, Pointer value) {
        System.out.println("Notification: " + Integer.toHexString(code));
    }
}
```

I set the callback function. However problems start at runtime. Callback function is executed only once, and then java application fails with non-zero exit value -1073740791. hs_err_pid* log file is not generated.

Is there something wrong with the mapping? I could not find examples for mappings with void* as parameter. Generally void* is mapped as Pointer, is it different when it is used as a parameter?
Do I need to free memory after each callback? I tried to do `Native.free(Pointer.nativeValue(value));` inside callback, but this didn't solve the problem.

P.S. I did read [JNA - callback method with void* arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139013/jna-callback-method-with-void-arguments) stackoverflow question, but it doesn't seem to be my case. I declared callback as static member  `public static NatLib.NotifyFunc notifyFunction = new MyNotifyFuncImpl();` - this should keep the reference to callback function unchanged and not garbage collected during runtime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JNA - callback method with void\* arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139013/jna-callback-method-with-void-arguments)

Comment: @DanielWiddis unfortunately no. I read that question, but it seems that my case is different. I keep the strong reference to my callback function at runtime by declaring it static - `public static NatLib.NotifyFunc notifyFunction = new MyNotifyFuncImpl();`

Comment: Does the API tell you anything about what's expected at the Pointer location?  It's possible you might need to allocate memory of a certain size for it, e.g., `Pointer p = new Memory(size);`.  The crash suggests unallocated memory.

Comment: Searching that exit code seems to point to an underlying problem with the software/driver, often Nvidia.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can not use `Callback`, if it is a `__stdcall` function. In this case you need to implement `StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback`. So your code should be like this:

```
interface NotifyFunc extends StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback{
    void MyNotifyFunc(int code, Pointer value);
}
```

The reason behind this is that `__stdcall` is used to call functions of the Win32 API. And if you only use `Callback` Jna does not know it has to use these.